# Query with Inner Join, without diagrams only using object explorer and sp_help

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is very easy but I've tried this in different ways. I'm using the
[AdventureWorks2008R2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17NtqbgRpIjORsJt_WrxCPqpsWsSlE2bz/view?usp=sharing)
database and I need to obtain Salesorderid, Orderdate, orderqty, name, firstname, lastname from all the orders (SalesOrderHeader) with all the sold products (Product) and customers (Customer)

1. First one I saw my mistake but decided to start over again

```
    Select OrderDate,OrderQty,FirstName,LastName,Name,soh.SalesOrderID
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    Inner Join Sales.Customer sc on soh.CustomerID = sc.CustomerID
    Inner Join  Person.Person pp on soh.PersonID = pp.PersonID   <-- My mistake 
    Inner Join Purchasing.ProductVendor ppv on pp.BusinessEntityID = ppv.BusinessEntityID
    inner join Production.Product ppr on ppv.ProductID = ppr.ProductID
```

2. I made this one but it displays nothing

```
    Select OrderDate,OrderQty,FirstName,LastName,Name,soh.SalesOrderID
    From Person.BusinessEntity pbe
    inner join person.person pp on pbe.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
    inner join sales.store ss on pbe.BusinessEntityID = ss.BusinessEntityID
    inner join sales.SalesOrderHeader soh on ss.SalesPersonID = soh.SalesPersonID
    inner join sales.Customer sc on soh.CustomerID = sc.CustomerID
    inner join sales.SalesOrderDetail ppo on  soh.SalesOrderID = ppo.SalesOrderID;
```

I was using the sphelp method, but I don´t know if you can give some tips on how to find the relation between each table without a diagram, I´m struggling with that part, also I try to use the object explorer as well.
For example:

[image]

In the above picture from my understanding is that the Sales.SalesOrderDetail has a primary key named SalesOrderId then SalesOrderHeader has a foreign key of this same one, same as SpecialOfferProduct,so that said I should be able to make a join between SalesOrderDetail and SalesOrderHeader, using SalesOrderID
I think that´s my main issue, sorry for all the bother I´m having trouble understanding this

Comment: First of all, try to finf out which join eliminates the results in your second query: I would start with salesorderheader and a join to salesorderdetail. Then add a join to store, then person and so on...

Comment: What is the essential part of question: how to create the query with desired output or how to find the dependencies? For the first question you should provide sample input, desired output and describe, what is the difference between it and output of your query. For the second one you can check this doc article: [View Foreign Key Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-foreign-key-properties?view=sql-server-ver15). But in general data model should be described externally, because FK constraints are not always used (for ex in DWH it is rare case)